# She hoped to have done

Tags: negation, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect

I saw a sentence

***She hoped to have done***

Or a sentence, created with the same structure. I don'tunderstand how it works. Then I saw a full version of it:

***She hoped*** that **she had done**

So, it's like a combination of **Past Simple(hoped)** + **Past Perfect(had done)** but combining them we can't have **Past Perfect**, we have  only **perfect infinitive**.

When I later saw

***She can't have done***

I didn't understand it, too. Since then I've been trying to create a full version of it which would be clear for me. I tried

***It can't be possible*** that **she has done** - I was told it was incorrect

***It can't be true*** that **she has done** - I was told it was incorrect, too

I also have such variants:

***It can't be real*** that **she has done**

***There can't be a possibility*** that **she has done it**

***There can't be a probability*** that **she has done it**

Is there any sentence among those I wrote which can be equaled to **"She can't have done"**?

Comment: The second phrase in the question is *not* a "full version" of the first phrase. They use different verb tenses in part, and they also have different meanings. Your question is far too broad. It's referencing a large number of different verb tenses and constructions, and then asking which is correct. As far as I can tell, the question boils down to this essentially: *I don't understand the meaning of **she can't have done**.* Most of the rest of the question can be stripped out. What is it about *she can't have done* that is confusing—and what do you mean when you say "full version"?

Comment: "She hoped to have done" is not the same as "She hoped that she had done"? But there's such an example - "He pretended to have lost her number and so had been unable to contact her. (or He pretended that he had lost her number …)" on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked. It has the same structe I descriped - whether a short version (She hoped to have done = She hoped that she had done/He pretended to have lost = He pretended that he had lost)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main source of confusion is your idea of a "full version" of each phrase. As is mentioned in the comments, the second phrase isn't a "full version" of the first phrase. In fact, it's no more "full" than the first phrase.

Now, let's start at the beginning of your post. You claimed not to have understood the following:

> She hoped **to have done**...

What you call the "full version," namely

> She hoped *that **she had done***...

has the same meaning. In your first example, the perfect infinitive just substitutes for the subordinate clause.

Now, to answer your question: *can't* is used in that context to imply that **the speaker does not believe that it is possible that something happened**. Let me use it in the present tense to show you what I mean. Let's say two people are having a conversation.

> Person 1: Hey, do you know that [the average cloud weighs 1.1 million pounds](https://www.sciencealert.com/this-is-how-much-a-cloud-weighs#:~:text=Researchers%20have%20calculated%20that%20the,or%201.1%20million%20pounds!).)?
>
> Person 2: No way! That **can't be** true.

What Person 2 is saying is:

> Person 2: No way! **I don't believe that it is possible that** that **is** true.

Let's say that the people are talking about something that happened in the past.

> Person 1: Hey, do you know that [the guy who jumped from space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Baumgartner) fell at almost 1,400 kilometres per hour?
>
> Person 2: No way! He **can't have fallen** that fast.

... where Person 2 is saying

> Person 2: No way! **I don't believe that it is possible that he fell** that fast.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: 1) Under full version I mean separating into tenses(She hoped-Past Simple that she had done-Past Perfect) just not to have everything mixed(She hoped to have done). 2) If "can't" means "The speaker does not believe that it is possible that something" then it can be the "full version" I mean. 3) "he can't have fallen that fast" - I don't understand this example because the context is about Past(jumped, fell), how can we use "can't" if it's supposed for Present? If to write a "full version" - "It can't be true that he fell/has fallen" - it'll be clear for me.

Comment: This case "can't" relates to something what I can't believe now but not to the jump itself because "can't" is present but jumping was in the past.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Modal verbs can sometimes be used for **deduction**. We use them when we want to express how certain we are as to whether something is true. _**Can't have [verb]**_ is a construction that shows that the speaker does not believe that it is possible that something happened. It's a very specific case, which is why it may seem to go against what you previously learned about modal verbs. Here's a link that may help you: [Modals – deductions about the past](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/modals-deductions-about-the-past)

Comment: " the speaker does not believe that it is possible that something happened" - So, can I equal "She can't have done" to "I can't believe she did/has done it" and then to my original "It can't be real that she did/has done it"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Your first example seems to suggest _definitively_ that she did something: "_can't have_" doesn't share that level of certainty. Your original sentence is okay, but I would swap "real" for "possible".

Comment: 1) It suggests definitively that she did something because of "I can't believe"?  But it's the original description of "can't have". The speaker doesn't believe it is possible = "I don't/can't believe that she has done/did it" 2) Okay, "possible" is better 3) Does it matter whether it's Past Simple or Present Perfect? "It can't be possible that she DID it" vs "It can't be possible that she HAS DONE it?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko When you say "I can't believe **she did/has done it**," whatever you can't believe has to have happened. It's suggested in the sentence. That's what I meant when I said that it suggested definitively that she did something. "I can't believe ..." is the same as saying "I am surprised/shocked that ..." When you say "She can't **have done it**," there's no suggestion as to whether she did it or not. What it suggests is that **you don't think it's possible that she did it**. Maybe she did it; maybe she didn't. It isn't clear.

Comment: 1) Clear. I just tried to use the word "can't" in a full sentence because the original phrase had "can't", too. This way "It can't be possible" would work instead of "I can't believe" 2) What about Past SImple vs Present Perfect in the second part? It can be either or no?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko They're different tenses. It depends.

Comment: No, of course, they are different but can "She can't have done" be written both with "...has done" and "...did" or it's only "...did"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109046/discussion-between-kman3-and-michael-azarenko).